# Material-UI SSR markup doesn't match client

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering

I'm using MaterialUI w/ React 16 w/ server-side rendering.  Everything seems to be wroking, but React is complaining about the server-side and client-side markups not matching.  What am I doing wrong?

React Warning: `Warning: Prop 'htmlFor' did not match. Server: "undefined-undefined-CurrentValue-9124" Client: "undefined-undefined-CurrentValue-51839"`

```
        <TextField
          className="mr-3"
          disabled={true}
          floatingLabelText="Current Value"
          value={props.inputValue}
        />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug that won't be there much longer once MUI 1.0 is released.  Adding an `id` attribute to input fields makes the warning go away for now.

Details here: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/9033#issuecomment-342569426